# Django Abstract User Error

Tags: django, django-users

I am working on extending the User class based on the docs with the code below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
  some_extra_data = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

However, I'm returning the following error

```
Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'MyUser.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'MyUser.groups'.
```

I understand resolving this type of conflict by adding a related_name to FK. How would I resolve it in this scenario?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to set your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting to point to your MyUser model, so that Django knows not to initialise the default model. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Answer (score 6):

Add this line

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_name.MyUser"
```

in the `settings.py` it works.