# Custom User's and implementations with forms

Tags: python, django

I have a problem using django-registration-redux.

I want to add others fields to the User as birthday, telephone, etc but it's difficult for me extends User class in models. What's the best form to add these fields to my user and show it in the form registration and login?

Comment: I would consider changing the title, as it looks unrelated with the actual body of the question

Comment: Thanks, i think that this tittle is more appropiated with the body now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to follow these steps:

1. define your user model, adding your desird fields, e.g. `birth_date` and `photo`:

   ```
   # filename: myapp/models.py

   from django.db import models
   from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
   from datetime import datetime
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group

   class MyUser(AbstractUser):

       birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
       photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=..., null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("photo"))
   ```
2. create a custom registration form:

   ```
   # in file myapp/forms.py
   from django import forms
   from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

   class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

       birth_date = ...
       photo = ...
   ```
3. write a custom registration view:

   ```
   # in file myapp/views.py

   from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
   from .forms import MyRegistrationForm

   class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):

       form_class = MyRegistrationForm

       def register(self, request, form):

           user = super(MyRegistrationView, self).register(request, form)
           user.birth_date = form.cleaned_data["birth_date"]
           user.photo = form.cleaned_data["photo"]

           user.save()

           return user
   ```
4. tell the system you are going to use your custom user model

   ```
   # in file settings.py
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.MyUser"
   ```
5. add an url to invoke your custom registration view

   ```
   # in file urls.py

   from myapp.views import MyRegistrationView
   ...

   urlpatterns = [
       ...
       url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="registration_register"),
       ...
   ]
   ```

Comment: I tried it but in models.py i got:

ERRORS:
Loguear.MyUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'MyUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'MyUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
Loguear.MyUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'MyUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.

System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced). What would be the problem? (other similar errors appeared too)

Comment: it seems you forgot to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py`, or you did so in a settings file that you do not load. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703323/django-abstract-user-error

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was reading about this and I found that AUTH_USER_MODEL was deprecated... What are the implications in my proyect?

Comment: Can you please point me where you read so? It's new to me. BTW did you make it working?

Comment: I'm sorry for that... I was confused with auth_profile_module, AUTH_USER_MODEL is avaliable... However it doesnt work. When I try to make migrations it says "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to customuser without a default". (customuser is my model)

Comment: can you share your `customuser` definition?