# Django Reverse accessor error

Tags: python, django, accessor

I dont understand why some fields of my models clash.

I dont have any foreign key so why would they clash ?!

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
import datetime
import uuid

# Create your models here
class Patients(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    dob = models.DateField(datetime.date.today)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

Here is the error:

```
api.Patients.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Patients.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Patients.groups' or 'User.groups'.
api.Patients.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Patients.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Patients.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Patients.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'Patients.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Patients.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'Patients.user_permissions'.
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "I dont have any foreign key so why would they clash ?!" Define clash.Show us your error log and traceback.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the error i just edited my post

Comment: Do you have another model that inherits from `AbstractUser`?

Comment: Did you add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: @EvansMurithi no i don't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserManage.groups'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189402/auth-user-groups-fields-e304-reverse-accessor-for-user-groups-clashes-with)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to your `setting.py` file. Django needs to know that to initialise the default model. You can add that as follows:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.Patients'
```

Check this in the documentation [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703434/4575071

Comment: what should i put in the [] just the name of my model ? so this: AUTH_USER_MODEL = [Patient] ?

Comment: Your app name, is it `api`? if so then you will add `api.Patients`

Comment: It is api indeed but now i get this error: ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'api.patients', but app 'api' doesn't provide model 'patients'.

Comment: It should be `api.Patients` not `api.patients`

Comment: yea sorry i noticed, even with api.Partients it does not work same error

Comment: Do you have some old migrations? you may need to remove them.

Comment: I have just ran makemigrations then migrate again but still nothing

Comment: remove the folder migrations in your `api` app, then run `python manage.py makemigrations api` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: i guess the typo is only on here and not in your code, but just in case, you wrote 'api.Partients'

Comment: @ettanany that worked but i get another error ... I can run migrate fine but when i try to access my api through the browser using Http://127.0.0.0:8000/patients/patient i get the following error: 
OperationalError: no such table: api_patients

Comment: Are you sure you run `python manage.py makemigrations api`? your database is configured correctly?

Comment: yes i did, that worked fine, i then tried to run python manage.py migrate and i am asked if i want to delete the content of auth and user because they are stale

Comment: here is the exact error message: The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    auth | user

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:

Comment: If your data is not important you can choose `yes` or even better delete your database if it is just for development and start all over again.

Comment: right i have sqlflush and i can now migrate, but i still get the error OperationalError: no such table: api_patients

Comment: This is an error different from what was mentioned in your question, I think it would be better to ask another question if the above issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

is using AbstractUser, then you should use into file settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.user'
```